# How to differentiate $f(a(y),y)$ with respect to $y$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, leibniz-integral-rule

How to differentiate $f(a(y),y)$ with respect to $y$? What rule do we need to apply on it?

Actually, I'm trying to understand the Leibniz’s Rule.
$$\displaystyle\frac{d}{d_y}\int_{a(y)}^{b(y)}f(x,y)dx=f(b(y),y)·\frac{d}{d_y}b(y)-f(a(y),y)·\frac{d}{d_y}a(y)+\int_{a(y)}^{b(y)}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)dx$$

What I tried to do was

Let $\displaystyle G(y)=\int_{a(y)}^{b(y)}f(x,y)dx=F(b(y),y)-F(a(y),y)$

$$\displaystyle\frac{d}{d_y}\int_{a(y)}^{b(y)}f(x,y)dx=\frac{d}{d_y}G(y)=\frac{d}{d_y}[F(b(y),y)-F(a(y),y)]=f(b(y),y)·\frac{d}{d_y}b(y)-f(a(y),y)·\frac{d}{d_y}a(y)$$

But obviously, I lost the last term $\int_{a(y)}^{b(y)}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)dx$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:
$$\frac{df(a,y)}{dy}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}\frac{da}{dy}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\left(a'\partial_a+\partial_y\right)f(a(y),y)$$
However this is not the best way to work out a proof for the Liebniz integral rule. Use the fact that:
$$\frac{df(x)}{dx}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
so we can do this to our integral:
$$I'=\frac{d}{dy}\int_{a(y)}^{b(y)}f(x,y)dx=\lim_{h\to0}\frac 1h\left[\int_{a(y+h)}^{b(y+h)}f(x,y+h)dx-\int_{a(y)}^{b(y)}f(x,y)dy\right]$$
Now we can manipulate this in some ways by noticing:
$$\int_{a(y+h)}^{b(y+h)}f(x,y+h)dx=\int_{a(y)}^{b(y)}f(x,y+h)dx+\int_{b(y)}^{b(y+h)}f(x,y+h)dx-\int_{a(y)}^{a(y+h)}f(x,y+h)dx$$

---

Now the terms in our limit become:
$$\int_{a(y)}^{b(y)}\frac{f(x,y+h)-f(x,y)}{h}dx+\frac 1h\int_{b(y)}^{b(y+h)}f(x,y+h)dx-\frac 1h\int_{a(y)}^{a(y+h)}f(x,y+h)dx$$
you should be able to see now where this is going

---

$$I'=\int_{a(y)}^{b(y)}\partial_yf(x,y)dx+b'f(b,y)-a'f(a,y)$$

Comment: Excellent answer! Could you tell me what's the rule to differentiate $f(a(y),y)$? Like where can I find it? Why do we sum up $\alpha'\partial_{\alpha}+\partial_y$ but not multiply them instead?

Comment: It is called the total derivative and it applies to finding $df(x_1,x_2,...)$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20total%20derivative,not%20just%20a%20single%20one.

Comment: Yea, I get it. Thank you so much!